# canvas lms : can't modify frozen Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, canvas-lms

RuntimeError in UsersController#user_dashboard

can't modify frozen Array

```
RAILS_ROOT: /home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms/app/models/account_notification.rb:36:in `reject!'
/home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms/app/models/account_notification.rb:36:in `block in for_user_and_account'
/home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms/lib/stubs/shard.rb:50:in `activate'
/home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms/app/models/account_notification.rb:27:in `for_user_and_account'
/home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:294:in `user_dashboard'
/home/pavan/projects/schoolify_options/canvas-lms/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:120:in `set_locale'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"user_id"=>nil}
```

Show session dump
Response

Headers:

```
{"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache",
 "X-Canvas-User-Id"=>"1",
 "Content-Type"=>""}
```

Comment: Just FYI -- showing a session dump without asking a question isn't too helpful. I'm assuming the problem is that you loaded up this gem, and your application has produced this error. Can you confirm or correct this?

Comment: Hey, I am so sorry, Yes, I am using canvas LMS, and installed using : https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms

No, when every thing setup for development, and I tried login using credentials, I am getting the above error.